# AWS mapreduce hive SSH into datanode

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, hive

Any one has any experience log into the datanode for mapreduce instance(HIVE) in AWS...

I only have the access to the master node but want to log into the datanode to do somework.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the first line of your question.

Log into the master node and ssh to the slave from there(assuming you have passwordless ssh enabled from master to all the slaves)

Comment: @B.Mr.W. : You are welcome. If it works the way you wanted, you can mark it so that someone else can benefit from it.